# line break in description label

Tags: beamer, description

I have a description label (or title) that is a bit long and I wanted to break it into two lines. I managed to do it in the following, but the second line of the description title does not line up with the second line of the first `\item`. Is there a way to fix this? MWE follows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\mode<handout>{ \usecolortheme{seahorse} \usecolortheme{rose} }
\useinnertheme{circles}
\usefonttheme[mathonly]{serif}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Course Logistics (cont'd)}
\begin{description}

 \item [{\parbox[t]{1.8cm}{Late\\assignments}} ]
   \begin{itemize}
      \item \small{Late assignments will be accepted for 48 hours past the due date, but...}
      \item For each 24 hour past the due date, a 5\% penalty will be applied off the top.
      \item Solutions will be posted after 48 hours at which point no further submissions are accepted
   \end{itemize}
\end{description}
\note{ }
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hide the depth of the parbox:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\mode<handout>{ \usecolortheme{seahorse} \usecolortheme{rose} }
\useinnertheme{circles}
\usefonttheme[mathonly]{serif}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Course Logistics (cont'd)}
\begin{description}

 \item [\smash{\parbox[t]{1.8cm}{Late\\assignments}} ]
   \begin{itemize}
      \item \small{Late assignments will be accepted for 48 hours past the due date, but...}
      \item For each 24 hour past the due date, a 5\% penalty will be applied off the top.
      \item Solutions will be posted after 48 hours at which point no further submissions are accepted
   \end{itemize}
\end{description}
\note{ }
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. I'd suggest changing `\small{Late assignments ...}` to `{\small Late assignments  ...}`.

Comment: Wow, thanks. I did not know anything  about \smash.